# Two styles with different colors

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is that possible to have two styles for one element with different colors?

In other words, lets suppose I have following HTML code:

```
<table class='my_table'>
<th class="style1 style2">LastName</th>
...
</table>
```

and following CSS:

```
.my_table th.style1 { 
    background: #aaaaaa; 
}

.my_table th.style2 { 
    background: #bbbbbb; 
}
```

I understand that I can remove one style with JavaScript for some condition. But I would like to have two styles and one of them should override another. Is that possible?

Comment: Have you tried this? One of them will override the other one.

Comment: Yes, I have tries but what is there any logic here? Maybe it order is important? What will override what?

Comment: Typo in your code? Maybe `<th class="style1 style2">`?

Comment: Its posible with php. If you have for exampple 4 rows then 2 of them will have another background

Comment: Have a look at CSS Specificity, perhaps that will answer some of your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use any number of classes on an element. CSS uses both the declaration order and the [specificity of the selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) to decide which will be overriden.

For example, if the specificity is the same, the last one is used:

```
.style1 { 
    background: #aaaaaa; 
}

.style2 { 
    background: #bbbbbb; 
}
```

Otherwise, the most specific will be used (the first one on the example below):

```
.my_table th.style1 { 
    background: #aaaaaa; 
}

.style2 { 
    background: #bbbbbb; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The last defined styles (not classes in your class attribute) should be applied on your element, to answer your question. But if somewhere was made use of the !important keyword, the results can come very strange to you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use more than one class for an element, and all style rules for those classes are applied.

If rules conflict, the rule that is most specific overrides the other. If rules are equally specific, the last rule applies.

Example:

```
<table class="my_table">
    <tr>
        <th class="style1">Style 1</th>
        <th class="style2">Style 2</th>
        <th class="style1 style2">Style 1 and 2</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The third cell will get the background from `style2`, as it is defined last in the style sheet.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jsLP5/

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can apply more than one class to an element, and if there are competing definitions for the same CSS elements then one will override the other.

Comment: The question is what is algo for choose the one under another?

Answer (score 0):

You can have as many style definitions as you want in general or for a specific element. Which one is used is based off the css specificity (scope). You can read more here: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Answer (score 0):

yes u can

```
       <th class="style1 style2">LastName</th>
```

and the css is yours
as it discribed here

http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/qt/tipcssmulticlas.htm

Answer (score 0):

For the given code, the background color used is #bbbbbb, since other things being equal, as they are here, the latter declaration wins, by the [cascade rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascade). This means the order of the CSS declarations. The order of class names in the `class` attribute is immaterial.